Why does this intersection point lie on the line y=x?
The answer could be staring me in the face, but if it is I don't see it. I was looking to evaluate the integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{sinh(x)} dx$$
Doing integration by parts with u=x and $\frac{dv}{dx}$ = csch(x) results in the following:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{sinh(x)} dx=\int_0^\infty -ln(tanh(\frac{x}{2}))dx$$
I plotted these two integrands in Desmos to compare the areas under the two curves, and I noticed that they intersect at the point  $(0.88137,0.88137)$. My question is why does this point have both coordinates the same? It probably has something to do with the integrals being equal, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Okay at least to make sense of the quantity $0.88137$, that is the value of $asinh(1)$. Consider points where both integrands intersect $y = x$. For the first one, $x = x/\sinh(x) \implies \sinh(x) = 1 \implies x = asinh(1)$. For the second, $x = -\ln(\tanh(x/2)) \implies e^{-x} = \tanh(x/2) \implies x = \log(1 + \sqrt{2}) = asinh(1)$. The integrands intersecting at a single point wouldn't make the integrals equal though

I see now lol. I was initially thinking it was a coincidence, and that the digits just happened to match up, but the real coincidence is that these two functions just happen to appear in related integrals

$$\text{Let}\quad\begin{cases}
y_1(x)=\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\\
y_2(x)=-\ln(\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))
\end{cases}$$
First : Solve the equation $\quad y_1(x)=\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}=x$
$\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}=1\quad\implies\quad \sinh(x)=1=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\quad\implies\quad e^{2x}-2e^x-1=0\quad\implies\quad e^x=1+\sqrt{2}$
$$x=\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$$
Second : Solve the equation $\quad y_2(x)=-\ln(\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))=x$
$\tanh(\frac{x}{2})=e^{-x}\quad\implies\quad \frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}=\frac{e^{x}-1}{e^{x}+1}=e^{-x}\quad\implies\quad e^{2x}-2e^x-1=0$
$$x=\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$$
Thus the two equations lead to the same root :
$$y_1(x)=y_2(x)=x=\ln(1+\sqrt{2})\simeq 0.881373587019543$$
Of course this doesn't imply that the antiderivatives be the same :
$$\int \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}dx=x\ln(\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))+\text{Li}_2(-e^{-x})-\text{Li}_2(e^{-x})+\text{constant}$$
$$\int -\ln(\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))dx=\ln(\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))\ln(1+\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))-\text{Li}_2(-\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))-\text{Li}_2(1-\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))+\text{constant}$$
$\text{Li}_2$ is the polylogarithm function of second order.
The two indefinite integrals ane not equal but the definite integrals from zero to infinity are equal :
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}dx=\int_0^\infty -\ln(\tanh(\frac{x}{2}))dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$
